# mongodb : delete documents with combinations criterias

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents like :

{
  prop1:string,
  prop2:string
}

What I would like to do is deleting all the documents that match one of the following conditions:

1. condition 1 : **prop1:"a" AND prop2:"b"**
2. condition 2 : **prop1:"c" AND prop2:"d"**

What I am doing is :

```
myCollection.deleteMany(
{
  prop1:{$in:["a","c"]}
  prop2:{$in:["b","d"]}
}
)
```

The problem with that is that I will be matching documents like :

```
{
  prop1:"a",
  prop2:"d"
}
```

or

```
{
  prop1:"c",
  prop2:"b"
}
```

But that's not what I want, I want to match only documents like :

```
{
  prop1:"a",
  prop2:"b"
}
```

or

```
{
  prop1:"c",
  prop2:"d"
}
```

Comment: You can try `{ prop1:"a", prop2:"b" } OR { prop1:"c", prop2:"d" }`, using the [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) logical operator.

Comment: ok thanks, will try once I get back to my desk